# change properties of DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

in my project I did change the width of all rows like this:

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.Height = 100;
    }
```

and the result: (i've changed some back colors)
[image]

but i want the `textbox` to be like this

[image]

i have seen [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12265/How-to-add-other-controls-to-DataGrid-Part-I) but i am not convenient with it, any idea to how can i insert a `textbox` or change the width of the `textbox` so it appear to the user as normal `textbox`

Comment: Do you have to use WinForms? This is pretty straight forward using WPF.

Comment: i know it will be easier, but i know nothing about WPF

Comment: If you're in the process of learning I'd really encourage you to forget about WinForms and go straight to WPF.

Why? - read this article/tutorial ([link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/319631-making-the-transition-from-winforms-to-wpf-part-1/)) - it's what made me change my focus from WinForms to WPF - and I'm SO happy I did!

Comment: Your column *is* functionally a TextBox. If by "appearing as a normal textbox" you mean the styling you applied in the picture, I would suggest figuring out a way to draw the cell yourself using the CellPainting event instead of deriving your own type, or trying to embed other controls into the cells. Perhaps you could set the default style of the cell to have a gray background, then draw the rectangle in the center of the cell. As long as your font size isn't larger than the box, it should appear as if the cursor is centralized to that rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `DataGridViewCellStyle`. It may or may not contain what you want but I use it to format my cell style.Else, like @glace said you can always use `CellPainting` if you want to have the exact same style as a normal textbox

`DataGridViewCellStyle`:

1.go into the design of your form

2.right click on the dgv and select modify column

3.choose a column and look for the `DefaultCellStyle` property

4.click the little button in the property field and customize your field

**Note: Your can always change your CellStyle in your code by giving the cell a new `DataGridViewCellStyle`

`CellPainting`:

```
 if (e.ColumnIndex != -1 && e.RowIndex != -1 && dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText == "TEXTBOX")
        {
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);
            Icon ico = new Icon("your_filename.ico");
            e.Graphics.DrawIcon(ico, e.CellBounds.Left + ((dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width - 16) / 2), e.CellBounds.Top + 3);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Just change the bound number(16 and 3), the dgv name and the HeaderText(TEXTBOX) with your value and it should be ok

**Note this draw the rectangle over the text, draw it under. :)